# Copiar archivos .sql del servidor a mi pc por medio de un batch

Tags: mysql, cmd, batch

Tengo una tarea programada que realiza BackUps de mi base de datos diariamente en el servidor y en mi pc tengo un bath que se ejecuta a determinada hora copiando los archivos sql que se generan en el servidor y copiandolos en mi pc.
Con el siguiente codigo hago la copia por cmd del servidor a mi pc:

Comando que ejecuto en mi pc:

```
xcopy /y \\Ip donde estan los archivos\c$\xampp\htdocs\Carpeta de origen\Sub 
Carpeta\cron\sqlBackup\*.sql C:\xampp\htdocs\Carpeta de destino
```

Detalle del comando:

- Lugar donde estan los archivos en el servidor que se copian:

  - \Ip donde estan los archivos\c$\xampp\htdocs\Carpeta de origen\Sub 
    Carpeta\cron\sqlBackup*.sql*
- Carpeta de destino en mi pc donde se pegan / guardan:

  - C:\xampp\htdocs\Carpeta de destino

Como puedo hacer para que sea al reves y ejecutarlo desde el servidor en la misma tarea que hace los backUps, o sea, acceder a la carpeta donde estan en el server copiarlos y pegarlos en en mi pc por medio del ip.
Calculo que seria como el comando de arriba pero tendria que ser al reves pero no me sale.

Comment: que sistema operativo tiene tu servidor

Comment: Window Server 2012 (creo)

Comment: cambiando el orden :V xcopy /y  C:\xampp\htdocs\Carpeta de destino \\Ip donde estan los archivos\c$\xampp\htdocs\Carpeta de origen\Sub 
Carpeta\cron\sqlBackup\*.sql

Comment: Ahi queda: xcopy /y C:\xampp\htdocs\carpeta\subCarpeta\cron\sqlBackup\*.sql \\Mi Ip\c$\xampp\htdocs\carpeta era solo cambiar los ip de luegar y poner el correspondiente -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```
xcopy /y C:\xampp\htdocs\carpeta\subCarpeta\cron\sqlBackup\*.sql 
\\Mi Ip\c$\xampp\htdocs\carpeta
```

Era solo dar vuelta los Ip y poner el correspondiente.